# Best Way to create Adjacency List in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

In general, to create Adjacency list of n node in java, we need to create an extra loop to fill the list with empty list like below-

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    adj.add(new ArrayList<>());
```

Now we had to had to add the elements,but because of this extra loop its wasting the time.
Is there any other best way to create the adjacency list??????

Comment: At some point you have to create the list. You can of course do that lazily when you need it the first time and add something to it. Probably not worth the effort though. Of which adjacency list sizes are we talking here? 1 million x 1 million? Or why do you care for the _10 nanoseconds_ to save here?

Comment: No it is not wasting the time. Just creating `n` array lists is not going to take much time unless you are talking of the order of millions. Your algorithm to process the graph needs to be efficient.

Comment: see the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024638/adjacency-list-with-o1-look-up-time-using-hashset

Answer (score 1):

If I need to make a compact representation of a graph, and I can get the neighbors for each vertex in sequence, I often do it like this:

```
//Concatenated adjacency lists for each vertex in order
ArrayList<Integer> adjList = new ArrayList<>();

//For each vertex, the end of its adjacency list in adjList
ArrayList<Integer> adjListEnds = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<num_vertexes; ++i) {
    for (int adj : getNeighbors(i)) {
        adjList.add(adj);
    }
    adjListEnds.add(adjList.size());
}
```

Now, to get the neighbors of any vertex:

```
int s = vertex>0 ? adjListEnds.get(vertex-1) : 0;
int e = adjListEnds.get(vertex);
for (int i = s; i<e; ++i) {
    processNeighbor(vertext, adjList.get(i));
}
```

Of course, if you want it to be *really* compact, then you should use something *like* an array list that holds primitive `int`s instead of `Integer`s.   Sometimes I roll my own.  Sometimes I use gnu trove.